# JFace/SWT multiline TableViewer rows

Tags: java, swt, jface

Is it possible to get multiline (say 2-line) row in JFace tableViewer? I want my long text part spreaded between two lines, and my short lines aligner vertically in the cell. How can I achive that result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table control itself does not support this. You will have to paint the content of those cells yourself. There's an official [example (Snippet006TableMultiLineCells)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets#Snippet006TableMultiLineCells) on how to do that.